# how to print "Html" without opening the "print popup" in "angular"?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to print "Html" without an open popup window.

```
print() {
    let printdiv;
    let Win;

    printdiv= document.getElementById('print_section').innerHTML;
    Win= window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    Win.document.open();
    Win.document.write(printdiv);
    Win.document.close();
}
```

```
<div id="print_section">
    // html code
</div>
<button (click)="print()">Print</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean "print" as in "getting a sheet of paper out of a printer"?

Comment: how to generate a "pdf" and print it with a single click? (without opening the browser window)

Comment: There are js libs that can create PDFs in the browser. I think you could create a button to create and "download" a PDF with theese libs. Search for "javascript create pdf".